# Is this an example of type erasure in Scala?

Tags: scala, type-erasure

Is this an example of type erasure in Scala?

```
(None: Option[Int]) == (None: Option[String]) // true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the from the scala source:
`case object None extends Option[Nothing]`

Before erasure both would be `None[Nothing]` because only a single instance of `None` exists. Yes this is an example of erasure, but not a realy good one.